# Trigger Div Click From Link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site http://www.thebalancedbody.ca/ and there is a pop out contact form on the left (Contact) which has this id `<div id="mycontactform">`.

There is also a link in the footer called CONTACT US

```
<a href="#"  title="CONTACT US">CONTACT US</a>
```

and I need this link to trigger the pop out contact form as if the contact tab was clicked manually.

Is this possible and how would I do it?

Thanks

JOnathan

Answer (score 3):

All of the suggested solutions should be working. But I think that you need to prevent the anchor's default action.

Add this code within a <script> tag in the <head> section of your document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contact").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); //stops the browser from following the link
        $("#contactable").click(); //opens contact form
        alert("Showing mycontactform"); //remove this when it's working
    });
});
```

You will need to add an 'id' tag to your contact anchor:

```
<a href="#" id="contact" title="Contact Us">CONTACT US</a>
```

You will also need to make sure you include jQuery in the <head> section of your document.

Add this line after the <head> tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: THIS IS DRIVING ME MAD - nothing I do seems to work - I have followed all instructions to the letter but to no avail - http://www.thebalancedbody.ca

Comment: As I mentioned in my own answer below - I think all of these will not work because the div - contactable is not written out - check the source - would that be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#divId").click();`.  This would fire the click event in the div with the specified ID.

The code given below is tested to work on Chrome and IE8.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("#myDiv").click(function() {
                    alert('Clicked!');
                });

                $("#myLink").click(function() {
                    $("#myDiv").click();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv">Some Text</div>
        <a id="myLink" href="#">Link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this <a href="#"  onClick="$('#contactable').click();" title="CONTACT US">CONTACT US</a> but it didn't work - any further ideas and is this correct?

Comment: so far everyone's answer has been more or less correct. I think the best answer now is really to dive into the jquery documentation. Try to fully grasp the concept of trigger mate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#contact").click(function () {
      $("#contactable").trigger('click');
    });
});

<a title="CONTACT US" href="#" id="contact">CONTACT US</a>
```

Comment: thanks - but this doesn't seem to work - I have tried different ways but can't seem to get it functioning

Comment: @Jonathan: Make sure that you include the jquery library in your doc. Also what error do you get with above code?

Comment: I don't get an error the cursor just jumps to the top - let me try adding the jquery library

Comment: I tried this and still no joy <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#contact").click(function () {
      $("#contactable").trigger('click');
    });
});
</script>
<a title="CONTACT US" href="#" id="contact">CONTACT US</a> 

I have added a new link bottom left for you to try http://www.thebalancedbody.ca

Comment: I have also changed the Div name to #mycontactfrom and still no joy

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {

        $('#foo').bind('click', function() {

            alert($(this).text());

        });

        // I used mouseover just because and 
        // for no reason. could be anything
        $('#bar').mouseover(function() {

            $('#foo').trigger('click');

        });
    });
```

html:

```
<a href="#" id="foo">foo</a>
<a href="#" id="bar">boo</a>
```

Comment: can't seem to get it to work - I don't know what it is triggered when you manually click on the CONTACT TAB (the green one) so can't seem to replicate this from the href link http://www.thebalancedbody.ca/

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
It looks like it is working as you want, except for that the page isn't at the top.  If that's the case check out jQuery's [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) function.  Also it looks like the 'contactable' div is not attached to the contact section, which could be a problem.  If that is not your problem, please edit the question to describe your current problem as it seems to be the interaction with the plugin rather than triggering a div click.  Good luck!

Old answer (no longer applicable as source has changed):

The problem in your situation is that the selector (#contact - gets elements with id equal to 'contact') in this :

```
$(function(){
    $("#contact").click(function () {
      $("#contactable").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Doesn't match the element you are wanting to add the event to :

```
<a href="#" title="CONTACT US">CONTACT US</a>
```

My suggestion would be to add a class to each element that you'll want to trigger the 'contactable' click like this:

```
<a href="#" class="contactable" title="CONTACT US">CONTACT US</a>
```

and

```
<a title="CONTACT US" href="#" id="contact" class="contactable">CONTACT US</a>
```

and then change your selector to use that class to assign the click function:

```
$(function(){
    $(".contactable").click(function () {
      $("#contactable").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit defeat on this one. I don't believe there is a solution based on the above answers (although I know they work in test environments), they just don't work in my exact case.

The reason for this is that if you do a view source on http://www.thebalancedbody.ca/ the DIV `#contactable`

Is not exposed in the source so no matter what I do these approaches won't work. The associated javascript for the pop out form is here, maybe that will give some clues?

```
/*
 * contactable 1.2.1 - jQuery Ajax contact form
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Philip Beel (http://www.theodin.co.uk/)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) 
 * and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.
 *
 * Revision: $Id: jquery.contactable.js 2010-01-18 $
 *
 */

//extend the plugin
(function($){

    //define the new for the plugin ans how to call it  
    $.fn.contactable = function(options) {
        //set default options  
        var defaults = {
            name: 'Name',
            email: 'Email',
            message : 'Message',
            subject : 'A contactable message',
            label_name: 'Name',
      label_email: 'E-Mail',
      label_website: 'Website',
      label_feedback: 'Your Feedback',
      label_send: 'SEND',
            recievedMsg : 'Thankyou for your message',
            notRecievedMsg : 'Sorry but your message could not be sent, try again later',
            disclaimer: 'Please feel free to get in touch, we value your feedback',
            hide_email: 'false',
      hide_website: 'false',
            fileMail: 'mail.php',
            hideOnSubmit: true
        };

        //call in the default otions
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        //act upon the element that is passed into the design    
        return this.each(function(options) {
            //construct the form
            div_form = '<div id="contactable"></div><form id="contactForm" method="" action=""><div id="loading"></div><div id="callback"></div><div class="holder">';
            div_form += '<p><label for="name">'+defaults.label_name+' <span class="red"> * </span></label><br /><input id="name_mc" class="contact" name="name" /></p>';
            if(defaults.hide_email == 'false'){
              div_form += '<p><label for="email">'+defaults.label_email+' <span class="red"> * </span></label><br /><input id="email_mc" class="contact" name="email" /></p>';
          }
          if(defaults.hide_website == 'false'){
              div_form += '<p><label for="email">'+defaults.label_website+' <span class="red"> * </span></label><br /><input id="website_mc" class="contact" name="url" /></p>';
          }
            div_form += '<p><label for="comment">'+defaults.label_feedback+' <span class="red"> * </span></label><br /><textarea id="comment_mc" name="comment" class="comment" rows="4" cols="30" ></textarea></p>';
            div_form += '<p><input class="submit" type="submit" value="'+defaults.label_send+'"/></p>';
            div_form += '<p class="disclaimer">'+defaults.disclaimer+'</p></div></form>';

            $(this).html(div_form);
            //show / hide function
            $('div#contactable').toggle(function() {
                $('#overlay').css({display: 'block'});
                $(this).animate({"marginLeft": "-=5px"}, "fast"); 
                $('#contactForm').animate({"marginLeft": "-=0px"}, "fast");
                $(this).animate({"marginLeft": "+=387px"}, "slow"); 
                $('#contactForm').animate({"marginLeft": "+=390px"}, "slow"); 
            }, 
            function() {
                $('#contactForm').animate({"marginLeft": "-=390px"}, "slow");
                $(this).animate({"marginLeft": "-=387px"}, "slow").animate({"marginLeft": "+=5px"}, "fast"); 
                $('#overlay').css({display: 'none'});
            });

            //validate the form 
            $("#contactForm").validate({
                //set the rules for the fild names
                rules: {
                    name: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    url: {
                        required: true,
                        url: true
                    },
                    comment: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                //set messages to appear inline
                    messages: {
                        name: "",
                        email: "",
                        url: "",
                        comment: ""
                    },          

                submitHandler: function() {
                    $('.holder').hide();
                    $('#loading').show();
                    name_val = $('#contactForm #name_mc').val();
                    if(defaults.hide_email == 'false') email_val = $('#contactForm #email_mc').val();
                    else email_val = 'nothing';
                    if(defaults.hide_website == 'false') website_val = $('#contactForm #website_mc').val();
                    else website_val = 'nothing';
                    comment_val = $('#contactForm #comment_mc').val();
                    $.post(defaults.fileMail,{subject:defaults.subject, name: name_val, email: email_val, website: website_val, comment:comment_val},
                    function(data){
                        $('#loading').css({display:'none'}); 
                        if( data == 'success') {
                            $('#callback').show().append(defaults.recievedMsg);
                            if(defaults.hideOnSubmit == true) {
                                //hide the tab after successful submition if requested
                                $('#contactForm').animate({dummy:1}, 2000).animate({"marginLeft": "-=450px"}, "slow");
                                $('div#contactable').animate({dummy:1}, 2000).animate({"marginLeft": "-=447px"}, "slow").animate({"marginLeft": "+=5px"}, "fast"); 
                                $('#overlay').css({display: 'none'});   
                            }
                        } else {
                            $('#callback').show().append(defaults.notRecievedMsg);
                        }
                    });     
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The other file that maybe useful is this:-

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Magic Contact
Plugin URI: http://blog.hunk.com.mx/magic-contact/
Description: is a simple and Elegant contact form for Wordpress, taking as it bases to <a href="http://theodin.co.uk/blog/ajax/contactable-jquery-plugin.html">Contactable</a> (jQuery Plugin) By <a href="http://theodin.co.uk/">Philip Beel</a>, After enabling this plugin visit <a href="options-general.php?page=magic-contact.php">the options page</a> to configure settings of sending mail.
Version: 0.1
Author: Hunk
Author URI: http://hunk.com.mx

Copyright 2010  Edgar G (email : ing.edgar@gmail.com)

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
*/

register_activation_hook( dirname(__FILE__) . '/main.php', 'magic_contact_activate' );

function magic_contact_activate(){
  if(!get_option('init_contact')){
    update_option( 'recipient_contact', get_bloginfo('admin_email') );
    update_option( 'subject_contact', 'A contactable message' );

    update_option( 'label_name_contact', 'Name' );
    update_option( 'label_email_contact', 'E-Mail' );
    update_option( 'label_website_contact', 'Website' );
    update_option( 'label_feedback_contact', 'Your Message' );
    update_option( 'label_send_contact', 'SEND' );
    update_option( 'recievedMsg_contact', 'Thank you for your message' );
    update_option( 'notRecievedMsg_contact', 'Sorry, your message could not be sent, try again later' );
    update_option( 'disclaimer_contact', 'Please feel free to get in touch, we value your feedback' );

    update_option( 'hide_email_contact', 'false' );
    update_option( 'hide_website_contact', 'false' );

    update_option( 'init_contact', 1 );
 }
}

// Add action links
add_action('plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'AddPluginActions');

function AddPluginActions($links) {
   $new_links = array();

   $new_links[] = '<a href="options-general.php?page=magic-contact.php">' . __('Settings') . '</a>';

   return array_merge($new_links, $links);
 }

add_action('admin_menu', 'mc_admin_actions');

function mc_admin_actions(){
  add_options_page("Magic Contact", "Magic Contact", 'manage_options',"magic-contact.php", "magic_contact_menu");
}

function magic_contact_menu(){   
  if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    if ( function_exists('current_user_can') && !current_user_can('manage_options') )
      die(__('Cheatin&#8217; uh?'));

    update_option( 'recipient_contact', $_POST['recipient_contact'] );
    update_option( 'subject_contact', $_POST['subject_contact'] );

    update_option( 'label_name_contact', $_POST['label_name_contact'] );
    update_option( 'label_email_contact', $_POST['label_email_contact'] );
    update_option( 'label_website_contact', $_POST['label_website_contact'] );
    update_option( 'label_feedback_contact', $_POST['label_feedback_contact'] );
    update_option( 'label_send_contact', $_POST['label_send_contact'] );
    update_option( 'recievedMsg_contact', $_POST['recievedMsg_contact'] );
    update_option( 'notRecievedMsg_contact', $_POST['notRecievedMsg_contact'] );
    update_option( 'disclaimer_contact', $_POST['disclaimer_contact'] );

    if ( isset( $_POST['hide_email_contact'] ) ) update_option( 'hide_email_contact', 'true' ); else update_option( 'hide_email_contact', 'false' );
        if ( isset( $_POST['hide_website_contact'] ) ) update_option( 'hide_website_contact', 'true' ); else update_option( 'hide_website_contact', 'false' );

  }
  include 'form-admin.php';
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'script_magic_contact');

function script_magic_contact(){

  $base = WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.str_replace(basename( __FILE__),"",plugin_basename(__FILE__)); 

  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.contactable', $base . 'contactable/jquery.contactable.js', array('jquery') , 3.1);
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.validate', $base . 'contactable/jquery.validate.pack.js', array('jquery') , 3.1);
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my_contactable', $base . 'my.contactable.php', array('jquery') , 3.1);
  wp_enqueue_style( 'contactable', $base . 'contactable/contactable.css' );

}

add_action('wp_footer','div_magic_contact');

function div_magic_contact(){
  echo '<div id="mycontactform"> </div>';
}

?>
```